# Query pre-created sub-folders in s3 using a single table schema in Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am exploring AWS Athena to query files in s3. We have a separate service that writes data into s3 in the following structure:

- data

  - /log1
  - /log2
  - /log3

All the files have the same schema.
Following is the schema of the files:

- id (a random string id)
- timestamp
- value

However, we need to be able to query data in a single folder - log1, log2 along with querying all the data together.
One option is to create separate tables for these. However, the sub folders log1, log2, etc. correspond to a device and these could be in numbers of 100s or thousands. These names would be dynamic and will be entered by the user for querying. Also, there are other query capabilities we need such as querying data between two timestamps, etc. Such queries will be fired at the /data folder level.

What would be a good way to structure the folders and the corresponding tables? I have read multiple questions that suggest partitioning, but for my use case, I don't really understand how to partition the data. I am extremely new to Athena and still learning. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partitioning will have an impact on how much data will be scanned with by every query and therefore improving the performance and lowering the cost - a good explanation can be found in [AWS Partitiong Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html):

> You can partition your data by any key. A common practice is to partition the data based on time, often leading to a multi-level partitioning scheme. For example, a customer who has data coming in every hour might decide to partition by year, month, date, and hour. Another customer, who has data coming from many different sources but loaded one time per day, may partition by a data source identifier and date.

> If you query a partitioned table and specify the partition in the WHERE clause, Athena scans the data only from that partition.

There are also some good recommendations regarding the partitions in [Top 10 Performance Tuning Tips for AWS Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/):

> When deciding the columns on which to partition, consider the following:
>
> - Columns that are used as filters are good candidates for partitioning.
> - Partitioning has a cost. As the number of partitions in your table increases, the higher the overhead of retrieving and processing the partition metadata, and the smaller your files. Partitioning too finely can wipe out the initial benefit.
> - If your data is heavily skewed to one partition value, and most queries use that value, then the overhead may wipe out the initial benefit.

Athena released lately a new feature called [Partition Projections](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html) which might be helpful in your case:

> In partition projection, partition values and locations are calculated from configuration rather than read from a repository like the AWS Glue Data Catalog. Because in-memory operations are often faster than remote operations, **partition projection can reduce the runtime of queries against highly partitioned tables.**

Especially the [Dynamic ID Partitioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection-dynamic-id-partitioning.html) could be interesting in your case.

How to partition in the end depends on the queries and how they are designed:

- Most queries include a time frame? Then you should consider date as a partition
- Most queries filter for a specific device (or a small amount of ids)? Then it might be a better choice to use device id as partition or at least trying to bucketing these. Also depends on the amount of rows per device to not make it too granular.
- You can also partition by date and device id.
- Since you already have a partition by device I would go for this in the beginning and use projections to query this data.

Comment: Yes I did explore the documentation today and found that Dynamic ID Partitioning works like a charm! I did not know partitioning can incur costs though. Thank you so much for a detailed response.